# Java ConcurrentHashMap and for each loop

Tags: java, thread-safety

Supposed I have the following `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> identificationDocuments = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String>();
        
identificationDocuments.put(1, "Passport");
identificationDocuments.put(2, "Driver's Licence");
```

How would I safely iterate over the map with a for each loop and append the value of each entry to a string?

Comment: What do you mean by ***safely***?

Comment: @sstan - How do I properly iterate over a thread-safe collection? I've seen examples with a while loop, but I want a for loop, how can you do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterators produced by a `ConcurrentHashMap` are [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly). That is:

> - they may proceed concurrently with other operations
> - they will never throw ConcurrentModificationException
> - they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

The last bullet-point is pretty important, an iterator returns a view of the map at some point since the creation of the iterator, to quote a different section of the [javadocs for ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration.

So when you loop through a keyset like the following, you need to double check if the item still exists in the collection:

```
for(Integer i: indentificationDocuments.keySet()){
    // Below line could be a problem, get(i) may not exist anymore but may still be in view of the iterator
    // someStringBuilder.append(indentificationDocuments.get(i));
    // Next line would work
    someStringBuilder.append(identificationDocuments.getOrDefault(i, ""));
}
```

The act of appending all the strings to the `StringBuilder` itself is safe, as long as you are doing it on one thread or have encapsulated the `StringBuilder` entirely in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If you are really asking this, but to iterate over any map you iterate over the `keySet()`

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");

for(Integer i: indentificationDocuments.keySet()){
        result.append(indentificationDocuments.get(i));
}

return result.toString();
```